# KnitR , Latex conditional display of Text and Code block

Tags: r, latex, knitr, pdflatex

How do i turn on/off display of perticular subsection based on some condition ? 
for example, i want to display following sub-section only when  `xyplotFacSpecTotVarTest.pdf` exist.

How can i do it ?

```
\subsection{Checksum: Factor, Specific, and Total Variance}
Perhaps the most basic test of a regression model is if the factor and specific variances sum to equal the total variance.  Here, we 
present this diagnostic as an xy-plot, with the sum of factor and specific variance on the x-axis and the total variance on the y-axis.  We 
expect the plotted points to line up tightly along the identity line.

\clearpage
\begin{figure}[!h]

\centering

\includegraphics{\Sexpr{image_dir}xyplotFacSpecTotVarTest.pdf}

\caption{Total Variance vs. Sum of Factor and Specific Variance, All Instruments Passing Exposure Model.}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: How do i handle situation where "xyplotFacSpecTotVarTest.pdf" doesn't exist. File generated off of contents in table, which in turn may or may not have data. final PDF generation process errors if it is missing "xyplotFacSpecTotVarTest.pdf" How Can i handle this scenario ?

Answer (score 6):

Put your sub-section in a different file, say, `sub.Rnw`. Then include it in your main document conditionally, e.g.

```
<<child = if (file.exists('foo.pdf')) 'sub.Rnw'>>=
@
```